# How can I change language of URL to single language In Yii?

Tags: php, yii, yii-extensions, yii-components

I have website built in Yii 1 framework and I want to change some URLs of website to German language. No multi-language.

Sample URL:

```
http://mywebsite.com/products
```

to

```
http://mywebsite.com/Produkte
```

Comment: How are your pages rendered? Via the urlroutes, or are they managed using CMS Pages?

Comment: Please share your `urlManager` config.